# Multithreaded tests with JMockit throw Exception

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, jmockit

UT in my project takes way too much time, that is why I wished to shorten this time by parallel execution of the tests. But while using a plugin to execute unit tests in parallel, JMockit throws `NullPointerException` and `ConcurrentModificationException`, probably due to same classes' conflicting `@Autowired` and `@Mocked` versions.

Anyone else had this issue? I'd love to hear some possible solutions to this.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Which tests throw the exception? What resource do they share? How do they share it? How is your project setup? Something `static` in an abstract test class? Some shared Spring Application Context? Some shared Arquillian stuffe? Or name something else :)

Comment: It is really obvious what is causing the issue, I mentioned `@Autowired` & `@Mocked` fields cause this issue, some of my test classes share the same logic classes in those two states. I also cannot get any detailed information on the specific test cases due to the behavior of the parallel executor plugin. Sorry for the lack of details.